# How to access the ID without using json(), while using HttpClient

Tags: json, angularjs, angular, http

I need to access the id of the object here. However, could not use json(), as it's in HttpClient. Please advise, what could be a solution. The error I'm facing is: "TS2339: Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'."
And without Json, the error is with 'id'. i.e. "TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'." (Please refer to: post['id'] = response.json().id;)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
// const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
@Component({
  selector: 'posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css'],
})
export class PostsComponent {
  posts: any[];
  private url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http
      .get(this.url) //{ headers }
      .subscribe((response: any[]) => {
        this.posts = response;
      });
  }
  createPost(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    let post = { title: input.value };
    this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(post)).subscribe((response) => {
      post['id'] = response.json().id;
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like below :

```
createPost(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    let post = { title: input.value };
    this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(post)).subscribe((response:any) => {
      post['id'] = response.id;
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

take a look at this sample :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o8b7ri?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts